# Cannot connect to Internet in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite l655-s5105 and have Ubuntu 12.04.

I have been working with it for almost a year now and it worked perfectly. I believe I updated some packages and the next time I turned on my computer it did not allow me to connect to my wireless nor the wired connection. I tried to reinstall the driver but it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: What **wireless** troubleshooting steps have you performed, to better define the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type

```
 sudo apt-get remove name_of_problem_software_install
```

Then remove whatever software you think caused it. If that doesn't work you can try plugging it in to the firewire and searching for drivers.

Also, see this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106568/my-wireless-has-suddenly-became-disabled-by-hardware-switch-bios-rfkill-fnf8?rq=1) for what looks to be a similar issue on a toshiba laptop